# Guardar data grid view en variables internas

Tags: c#

Cómo puedo guardar mi `dataGridView` en un array de objetos. Cada fila es un objeto donde cada columna es un atributo de ese objeto. Tengo mi array `sTcCnfArray` del tipo `sTcCnf`. No sé si hacerlo con un `BindingSource` (sería algo así):

```
BindingSource CantonesBindingSource;
CantonesBindingSource = (BindingSource)dataGridViewTcCnf.DataSource;?? (me pone que es null)
CantonesBindingSource.CopyTo(TcCnfArray, 0);
```

O también ir celda a celda asignando los valores (queda menos bien):

```
sTcCnfArray[0].IdApp = Convert.ToByte(datagridview1.Rows[0].Cells[0]);
```

etc.

Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Como estás cargando los datos en ese `DatagridView`?

Comment: por ahora manualmente desde la interfaz de usuario

Comment: La pregunta es importante, ya que depende de eso `DataSource` contiene algo o no, un tipo de datos u otro. En este caso, si lo metes manualmente obviamente datasource es null.En ese caso, la unica solucion es lo que haces, ir recorriendo la colección `Rows` para acceder manualmente a cada fila

Comment: La aplicación permitirá introducir los valores tanto manualmente desde la interfaz como desde un archivo XML por tanto podria hacer un if(DataSource==null) lo hago de una manera y si no es null lo hago de la otra no?

Comment: ConfData.TcCnf.TcCnfArray[i].IdTc = Convert.ToByte(oTcConfig.dataGridViewTcCnf.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);                  Cuando pongo esta línea me dice que es null pero en esa posición hay un 1. como puede ser?